# get result of a multiplication of two input tags into a different one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two inputs tags. one is quantity and the other is rate.

How can I show the result of the multiplication of those directly into a different input tag straight after the user stop typing?

I'm new to development and I'm finding my way. I'd like to have an input on where to start to sort this out.

Thank you

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: You should start by reading some basic tutos, that's the best way to learn

Comment: Research JQuery's keyup event and try something with that, it's really quite simple, and I am sure there are loads of example of this kind of functionality

Comment: I know about event click and I've been using jquery already. I just don't know in this case which is best.

Comment: @Valina: So what have you tried? Seriously if you can't work out something [as simple as this](http://jsfiddle.net/cvt5hsq6/) then you are really going to struggle being a developer. Just break the problem down into simple steps... 1) how do I get the value from an input? 2) how do I multiply two values? 3) how do I set a value in an input? ...problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps a little bit.... (Dirty... i know)

```
<input id="in1">
<input id="in2">
<input id="in3">

<script>
 var val1=0;
 var val2=0;
 var val3=0;
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#in1').keyup(function(){
     val1=$(this).val();
     val2=$('#in2').val();
     val3=parseInt(val1)*parseInt(val2);
     $('#in3').val(val3);
   });
   $('#in2').keyup(function(){
     val2=$(this).val();
     val1=$('#in1').val();
     val3=parseInt(val1)*parseInt(val2);
     $('#in3').val(val3);
   });
 });
</script>
```

NOT TESTED